# External hard drive unrecognizable in disk utility but found in System Information

Tags: hard-drive, disk-utility, external-disk

I've got a WD EasyStore 1TB external hard drive that won't show up in disk utility at all. I've tried multiple MacBooks and on my raspberry pi. The ONLY thing I can get to recognize the hard drive itself are the WD Drive Utilities (yuck), but when I try to erase it from there the application crashes. I have looked for a `fsck_hfs` or `fsck_exfat` process running to see if the machine is trying to repair the disk before it runs it at all. Nothing. When I try to reboot my MacBook with the drive connected to it, it stays stalled on the apple logo for as long as I'll let it. I can see that it is recognized as a USB connection in System Information, but it is not recognized as storage at all. Help, please!!!

Comment: A device can be recognized by the system (the USB to SATA bridge) but not function (the drive itself died).  The symptoms you describe here are addressed in the linked answer.

Answer (score 0):

If several Macs and a Pi have all failed to read the disk, then I'd suggest it's not a software problem.

It's likely that the hard drive has failed in some way. WD drives are known to have poor enclosures, but getting the drive out of a portable drive shell is not easy.

You can try taking it to a data recovery firm, but it will be expensive. If you have a backup, just toss it. (This one, not the backup.)

Otherwise, you can try data recovery software yourself, but if the drive won't even be recognised, it's unlikely.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. It's a new drive, just over a week old, so it would be surprising to me if the drive itself was failing already. That said, It seems I've exhausted all options on trying to fix it so I ran up to Best Buy and swapped it out for a new one. Hopefully it's just a fluke. Thanks again!

Comment: In any mass manufacturing process, 0.001% or so may slip past Quality Control.